# Faye on Heroku "error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, faye

I've installed a web app cloned from : https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Heroku-Cedar

I push it on heroku but it doesnt work.

In my log, this errors :

```
2014-01-22T11:06:51.110578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/faye.js host=my-url-faye-server.herokuapp.com request_id=72478a42-485c-4984-a3b9-3f9e252c2fdc fwd="82.240.110.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-22T11:06:51.482947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=my-url-faye-server.herokuapp.com request_id=36789c9a-d18d-46ac-bdf1-9b848ca50f7c fwd="82.240.110.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I dont know how to solve this problem, so i need help :)

Thanks for advance !